# Prove $ \sin x + \frac{ \sin3x }{3} + ... + \frac{ \sin((2n-1)x) }{2n-1} >0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Prove that for $ 0<x< \pi $, $$ \quad S_n(x) = \sin x + \frac{ \sin3x }{3} + ... + \frac{ \sin((2n-1)x) }{2n-1} >0 \quad \forall n = 1,2,... $$

Having trouble with this problem. This is an olympiad-style question, so an answer that doesn't use calculus or analysis would be preferred. A possible approach is induction, but for this we need to find a function in terms of $n$ and $x$ so that we can actually use the inductive step. If anyone has any ideas they would be appreciated.

If you really want to go down the calculus route (at this point I don't mind), then $ S_n' (x) = \cos x + \cos 3x + ... +\cos((2n-1)x) $ , which you can find a closed form for, but I don't know how useful that is.

Comment: My first idea would be to try addition formula $\sin(k+2x)$

Comment: @Carlos I don't understand your comment, at $x = \frac { \pi } {2} $ sequence is equal to $1 - \frac {1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + ... + \frac { (-1)^{2n} }{2n-1} $, which approaches $ \frac { \pi } {4} $

Comment: All + signs $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+2k}$ diverges according to wolfram alpha. You will also realize this by a comparison to harmonic series.

Comment: Would you accept an answer using complex numbers? =D.  (its not calculus after all....).

Comment: @mathguy If you can do one, I would accept it. I actually thought of this, but I don't really know how to deal with the changing denominator - I assume you're talking about expressing $ \sin x $ as $ \frac { e^{ix} - e^{-ix} } {2i} $ ?

Comment: @Physicist137 - One way we used to "cheat" (if you think about it though, not really cheating?) when I was doing this kind of math contests very many years ago was to use complex numbers, or calculus, or whatever, get a good understanding of the problem, and then use that to help find an elementary solution. I think everything is fair along the lines you are suggesting when it comes to contests!

Comment: @Cataline - I believe you meant to reply to Physicist137... anyway, what he means is consider $z = \cos x + i \sin x$, your sum is the imaginary part of $z + z^3/3 + \cdots$; find a closed form for that, take the imaginary part and you will have a closed (or "more" closed) form for the sum.

Comment: That's exactly what I was planning! However, I just realized.. to do this will require one integral. And since calculus is not allowed.... Althought its possible to circumvent the integral with algebraic manipulation... But it would get lengthy....

Comment: One potentially useful avenue is to graph the first few terms. Looks suspiciously like a square wave. A quick check reveals where the 4/pi term comes from, the Fourier transform. No calculus, but at least you have a hint about what it might be related to.

Comment: Confirming Carlos suspicious: If $n\to\infty$, this is a fourier series approximating a square signal that is positive from $0$ to $\pi$ and negative from $\pi$ to $2\pi$, with amplitude of $\pi/4$. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Is calculus not acceptable for olympiad? Many high school students learn calculus as official curriculum..

Comment: @i707107 I'll accept calculus, but the idea of Olympiad-style questions is that you never need calculus to solve them. We could attack this question with analysis, but since we know there is a non-calculus solution I would prefer to find that one, because I would learn much more from it. And more elementary solutions are usually nicer.

Comment: For a calculus solution, my first observation would be that the sum equals $\int_0^1 \sin x + t^2 \sin x + \cdots + t^{2n-2} \sin (2n-1) x \;\text{d}t$, then manipulate the integrand (multiply by $t$, use the complex-number trick, do some algebra)... still not clear if this will work.

Comment: @Cataline, to say that we'd "learn much more" from a non-calculus solution might be a bit too much! :) That is, even if you _can_ swim The Channel, is that really the point?

Comment: @mathguy: By doing that trick, you can write the sum as $\pi/4$ plus two integrals which can be bounded by $O(1/(n\sin x))$ and $O(1/(n^2\sin^2x))$ (I haven't worked out the constants yet). This will show that for $x$ not too close to $0$ or $\pi$, the sum is positive. A separate argument will be needed to show that the sum is positive for $x$ slightly larger than $0$ or slightly smaller than $\pi$.

Comment: @Carlos, It is indeed Fourier analysis that leads to the solution. But, I am curious to see if there is another solution that does not use calculus. I will put up my solution if anyone wants to see it.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - you only need the extra info at 0 (the function is vertically symmetric w.r.t $x = \pi /2$), and clearly for $x < \pi/(2n-1)$ the sum is positive. So this may work.

Comment: I remember seeing a solution yesterday using trig identities. Did the writer of the solution remove it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we want to avoid integration, we can obtain the result via summation by parts. Let

$$F_m(x) := \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \sin \bigl((2k+1)x\bigr).\tag{1}$$

Using the addition theorem for the cosine, we obtain

$$\sin(rx) = \frac{2\sin x \sin(rx)}{2\sin x} = \frac{\cos\bigl((r-1)x\bigr) - \cos \bigl((r+1)x\bigr)}{2\sin x}$$

and hence by telescoping

$$F_m(x) = \frac{1 - \cos (2mx)}{2\sin x}\tag{2}$$

when $x$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$. Since $1 - \cos (2mx) \geqslant 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $F_m(x) \geqslant 0$ for $0 < x < \pi$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus

\begin{align}
S_n(x) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{\sin \bigl((2k+1)x\bigr)}{2k+1}\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{F_{k+1}(x) - F_k(x)}{2k+1}\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{F_{k+1}(x)}{2k+1} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{F_k(x)}{2k+1}\\
&= \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{F_m(x)}{2m-1} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \frac{F_k(x)}{2k+1}\tag{$F_0 \equiv 0$}\\
&= \frac{F_n(x)}{2n-1} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \biggl(\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2k+1}\biggr) F_k(x)\\
&\geqslant 0,
\end{align}

since all terms on the right hand side are non-negative. The strict inequality $S_n(x) > 0$ for $x\in (0,\pi)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ follows because the term involving $F_1(x) = \sin x$ is strictly positive on $(0,\pi)$.

---

If we use integration, we first observe that since $\sin \bigl(m(\pi - x)\bigr) = (-1)^{m+1}\sin x$, we have the symmetry $S_n(\pi-x) = S_n(x)$, so it suffices to consider $0 < x \leqslant \pi/2$. Then we note that

$$S_n'(x) = \frac{\sin (2nx)}{2\sin x},\tag{3}$$

with more or less the same argument as above. Since clearly $S_n(0) = 0$, we have

$$S_n(x) = \int_0^x S_n'(t)\,dt = \int_0^x \frac{\sin (2nt)}{2\sin t}\,dt = \frac{1}{4n}\int_0^{2nx} \frac{\sin u}{\sin \frac{u}{2n}}\,du.$$

The denominator is strictly increasing on the interval of integration (since $0 < x \leqslant \pi/2$), and hence

$$\int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi} \frac{\sin u}{\sin \frac{u}{2n}}\,du = \int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi} \sin u\biggl( \frac{1}{\sin \frac{u}{2n}} - \frac{1}{\sin \frac{u+\pi}{2n}}\biggr)du > 0\tag{4}$$

for $0 \leqslant k < n$. Let $m = \bigl\lfloor \frac{2nx}{2\pi}\bigr\rfloor$, then

$$4nS_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi} \frac{\sin u}{\sin \frac{u}{2n}}\,du + \int_{2m\pi}^{2nx} \frac{\sin u}{\sin \frac{u}{2n}}\,du.$$

The last integral is strictly positive - if $2nx \leqslant (2m+1)\pi$, the integrand is strictly positive on the whole interval except the endpoints, if $(2m+1)\pi < 2nx < 2(m+1)\pi$, $(4)$ shows that $\int_{2m\pi}^{2nx}\dotsc\,du > \int_{2m\pi}^{2(m+1)\pi}\dotsc\,du > 0$ - unless $2nx = 2m\pi$. But in that case, we have $m \geqslant 1$, and the sum is strictly positive.

Comment: Very elementary and beautiful argument as desired by OP.+1