# Let $n$ be any positive integer and let $x \in (0, \pi)$. Prove that $\sin x+ \frac{\sin 3x}{3} + \cdots +\frac{\sin(2n-1)x}{2n-1}$ is positive.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I came across the following problem in a high school calculus exam paper. I do have the solution, but it took me quite a while to work it out and I think it's very clumsy. I'm curious to know if there is a simpler solution.

***Problem***

Let $n$ be any positive integer and let $x \in (0, \pi)$. Prove that

$$\sin{x} + \frac{\sin{3x}}{3} + \frac{\sin{5x}}{5} + \cdots +\frac{\sin{(2n-1)x}}{2n-1}$$ is positive.

Comment: Are you familiar with Lerch Transcendant $\phi$ functions? Because you can get this sum in closed form using them. (LOL -- if you think YOUR solution is clumsy, ...)

Comment: @MarkFischler Thinking that this is a highschool exam problem, I don't think it would be Lerch Transcendent functions. There's probably a trigonometric trick.

Comment: @james.nixon To me, it looks like that we can differentiate the sum w.r.t x, and get the sum of $\cos nx$, which then can be calculated by a geometric progress involved with $e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Looking at it, I was thinking look at properties of the derivative $\cos x + \cdots + \cos (2n-1)x$.  But that equals $\frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin x}$ which oscillates so I'm not sure how much traction you could get that way.

Comment: Let

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\big((2k-1)x\big)}{2k-1}$$

$f$ is continuous and periodic, so it has a maximum and a minimum.
Moreover it is differentiable so its derivative must vanish at extrema.
We have

$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\cos\big((2k-1)x\big)$$

Do you think you can look for solutions to $f'=0$?

Comment: @Huang Similar to what I meant by trigonometric trick, but I was off. That's definitely how to do it.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri My first line of attack was the same, but it turned out to be very difficult to prove that $f(x) > 0$ at the zeros of $f'(x)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876336/prove-sin-x-frac-sin3x-3-frac-sin2n-1x-2n-1-0

Answer (score 1):

Let the required sum be $S(x)$,

$$\begin{align*}
S(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(2k-1)x}{2k-1}\\
S'(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(2k-1)x\\
&= \Re \left[\sum_{k=1}^ne^{i(2k-1)x}\right]\\
&= \Re \left[e^{ix}\cdot\frac{1-e^{i2nx}}{1-e^{i2x}}\right]\\
&= \Re \left[e^{inx} \cdot \frac{e^{-inx} -e^{inx}}{e^{-ix} - e^{ix}}\right]\\
&= \Re\left[(\cos nx +i\sin nx)\cdot\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\right]\\
&= \frac{\sin 2nx}{2\sin x}
\end{align*}$$

Since $S(x) = S(\pi-x)$, it is sufficient to consider only $x \in (0,2\pi/4]$.

In the range $x\in(0,2\pi/4]$, $S'(x)$ has the same sign as $\sin 2nx$. Local minima of $S(x)$ (including the boundary case $x=0$) are at

$$\begin{align*}
2nx &= 2\pi k\\
x &= \frac{m}{2n}\cdot 2\pi, &&0\le m\le \frac n2,\quad m\in \mathbb N
\end{align*}$$

The difference between two adjacent local minima is

$$\begin{align*}
D &= S\left(\frac{m}{2n}\cdot 2\pi\right) - S\left(\frac{m-1}{2n}\cdot 2\pi\right)\\
&= \int_{\frac{m-1}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}^{\frac{m}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}S'(x)\ dx\\
&= \int_{\frac{m-1}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}^{\frac{m}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\frac{\sin 2nx}{2\sin x}dx\\
&= \int_{\frac{m-1}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}^{\frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\frac{\sin 2nx}{2\sin x}dx + \int_{\frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}^{\frac{m}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\frac{\sin 2nx}{2\sin x}dx\\
\end{align*}$$

The numerator $\sin 2nx$ is positive in the first integral, and negative in the second integral. Using the fact that $\sin x$ is increasing in $x\in(0,2\pi/4]$,

$$\begin{align*}
D &> \frac{\int_{\frac{m-1}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}^{\frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\sin 2nx\ dx}{2\sin \frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi} + \frac{\int_{\frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}^{\frac{m}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\sin 2nx\ dx}{2\sin\frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\\
&= \frac{\int_{\frac{m-1}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}^{\frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\sin 2nx\ dx + \int_{\frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}^{\frac{m}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\sin 2nx\ dx}{2\sin\frac{m-1/2}{2n}\cdot 2\pi}\\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

In other words, the values of $S$ at $x = 0, \frac{2\pi}{2n}, \frac{2\cdot 2\pi}{2n}, \cdots, \frac{\lfloor n/2\rfloor\cdot 2\pi}2$ are strictly increasing compared with the previous one, so they are all greater than $S(0) = 0$. Also, since these $x$'s are local minima, every other $x$ between them will also be greater than $S(0) = 0$.

Comment: I came up with pretty much the same solution, with a few minor changes in the precise details. I still think that this is not a solution expected of a high school student.